# Java Method Parameter Generics Type

Tags: java, generics

I have a class:

```
public abstract class BindingFragment<T extends ViewDataBinding> extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        T binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
        onViewBind(binding);
        onViewBind(createViewBind(view));
        onViewBind((T)DataBindingUtil.bind(view));
        onViewBind(DataBindingUtil.bind(view)); //this line compile error
    }`

    public abstract void onViewBind(T binding);

    private T createViewBind(View view){
        return DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
    }
}
```

The method `DataBindingUtil.bind(view)` signature is below:

`public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T bind(View root)`

I tested some ways to call `onViewBind(T binding)` in the class BindingFragment, but the line above `onViewBind(DataBindingUtil.bind(view))` could not pass.Could someone tell me why?

Comment: If you have written `DataBindingUtil` class, then you should consider changing the bind() method's return type. There is no point in using generics if only the return type is generic. How are you even creating the return object in `bind()` method?

Comment: Strange, it compiles fine for me. Can you please share the compiler's error?  Also, @Codebender is right, you don't want to return generic from the method without passing it's class as an argument. Strict typing and generics mechanism is designed to prevent errors in compile time, not to introduce them in runtime.

Comment: @Codebender Thanks very much. The class `DataBindingUtil` is from the android data bind library.

Comment: @Aivean Thanks ,too. I use Android Studio as my Android IDE. While I write it above, the IDE give me a compile error under the line. Maybe the IDE does that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide explicitly cast with T at `onViewBind(DataBindingUtil.bind(view)); //this line compile error`.

Because at below method you are accepting argument as T.

```
public abstract void onViewBind(T binding);
```

If you use below method then you do not need to provide any explicit casting.

```
public abstract void onViewBind(ViewDataBinding binding);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

The offending line

```
 onViewBind(DataBindingUtil.bind(view)); //this line compile error
```

compiles in Java 1.8 but not in Java 1.7 (when testing in Eclipse).
Right now compiler treatment of Java generic types is a moving target.

In Java 1.7 you can use

```
 onViewBind(DataBindingUtil.<T>bind(view));
```

to avoid the cast.

Comment: Thanks very much, I got it.